# Warning or Termination?

Tags: new-job, quitting

I was hired to perform a job that I was told did not require advance computer skills. The job had been newly created.

Then the company decided the job was in fact going to require advance computer skills and a decision was made to remove me from the job and transfer me to another newly created job. My salary and vacation accrual did not change but I was now placed on the top of the salary range of my new job.

I never received a 90 day performance review because I was told that the department did not do them.  I endured a lot of workplace bullying through this change. The disgruntled direct Manager I had left within my first year.

I received a verbal warning 2 months ago that was unjust. 0n 12/24/15 I received my 1st performance review stating I met standards but my now new Manager disclosed she did not think I was going to be able to perform my newly created job based on her 3 months observation of me. On 12/28/15 I received a performance written warning.Although I was led to believe she would work with me, I found out my position had been posted 6 days ago.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Depends a lot on where this is. In France, you're fine, in the US, look for another job.

Comment: Depends. In France, sometimes the employer bites the bullet & fires the employee anyways. It's costly(much more than in the States), but it happens. Signs are not good, in the OP, and the situation seems not nice to live in. Even in France, I'd give the advice of looking elsewhere. With less stress, thanks to the 3-months notice, but still.

Answer (score 7):

You're not happy and they're not happy.  It is probably best to start searching for new opportunities.  Once you have secured a new position, put in your 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

> I found out my position had been posted 6 days ago.

It does not mean it will replace you. May be they are looking for more candidates.(If we think positively)

As other side, You should ask to your manager that what improvement they want in your work so you can progress according to that. If you get proper guidance to progress then do efforts to try to match their goal. if you feel that they have decided to terminate your then start to find a new job right now.

Also if you think that this is not job for which you are actually looking for then find another job in which you have expertise and where you can give your best. Think about long term career and future.